# How to change a dtype of a vector column in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, dtype

I have a sparse vector column which I am converting to dense vectors via UDF. I would like to convert the types of vector values to float32 from float64 (PySpark dense vectors standard dtype is float64).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you, maybe overkill but I used something similar.
Technically untested code, but only as I modified it from code that was already running.

```
def float32_convert( vector ):
 new_list = []
 if vector is None:
  return new_list
 try:
  new_list = [ numpy.float32(np_float) for np_float in x.toArray() ] 
 except Exception as inst:
  print(type(inst))
  print(inst.args)
  print(inst)
 return new_list
```

I should mention for a dense vector I did use float, not sure if you have a very specific use case. If you actually need to convert to `float` from  `numpy.float64`:

```
def float64_convert( vector ):
 new_list = []
 if img_vector is None:
  return new_list
 try:
    new_list = [ np_float.item() for np_float in x ] )
 except Exception as inst:
  print(type(inst))
  print(inst.args)
  print(inst)
 return new_list
```

My original function had 2 loops but I don't remember why, I think I was using this inside a mapPartition.  I wish I'd documented it better.

```
def no_more_numpy( img_vector ):
 new_list = []
 if img_vector is None:
  return new_list
 try:
  for y in img_vector:
   for x in y:
    new_list.extend(  [ np_float.item() for np_float in x ] )
 except Exception as inst:
  print(type(inst))
  print(inst.args)
  print(inst)
 return new_list
```